# EngineYard SHA1 Contest Approaches

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

[EngineYard](http://www.engineyard.com/) is holding a constest [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/engine-yard-contest-challenge-phrase-and-dictionary/), where given a phrase and a dictionary of words, come up with a 12 word phrase whose SHA1 hash has the smallest hamming distance from the SHA1 hash of the given phrase.

A couple of sites are using cloud/crowd-sourcing to try to bruteforce it, while others are using CUDA and GPUs.  Some reports have the GPUs scoring mid-30 hamming distances, while the crowd-sourcing javascript have hamming distances in the 40s.

What would your approach to this contest be?  One approach per answer.

Contest Has Closed

Comment: Since it's a contest, why would people share their answers before the contest is over?

Comment: People not planning on entering (like me) could share their ideas.  Also, where it started yesterday, most people have a much bigger head start

Comment: @sanoz maybe they can come up with "blended" solutions like what they did in NetFlix? :)

Answer (score 1):

Options are pretty much (1) brute force, (2) exploit weaknesses in SHA-1. If you could solve this with a genetic algorithm in less than brute-force time, then I think that would constitute a weakness in SHA-1 by definition. Certainly if the genetic algorithm could produce an exact match in less than brute-force time, it would be.

Mind you, I don't know whether difficulty of finding a near-match is actually a required property of a cryptographic hash. Is a hash secure for all standard crypto applications if it's easy to find near matches, but still properly hard to find exact matches? If so, then there may be a middle ground where you use some property of SHA-1 which is not a weakness.

However, I suspect the reason the winning phrase must consist of exactly twelve words from a given dictionary is to be extra-confident that there cannot be a less-than-brute approach. Even if a technique were known for finding near-pre-images in SHA-1, adapting it to produce legal results would most likely be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

I was pondering whether or not a local search or genetic algorithm would work.  I don't think it would, where a small permutation (changing the capitalization of a letter) would create a completely new hash.

Is brute force really the best way?

Comment: If SHA1 was an ideal cryptographic hash then brute force would definitely be the best way. Since we know that SHA1 is less than ideal it opens the possibility that one of the flaws will make some other approach practical. But probably not, and almost certainly not in time for this contest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody can implement the ideas of [Xiayoun Wang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Xiaoyun) and her collegues?

See their book chapter on:
[Finding Collisions in the Full SHA-1](http://www.springerlink.com/content/26vljj3xhc28ux5m/)

and also this powerpoint presentation entitled [Cryptanalysis on SHA-1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220214002/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/Wang_SHA1-New-Result.pdf)

here's an excerpt of what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Xiaoyun) has to say about her:

> "In February 2005 it was reported that
> Wang and co-authors had found a method
> to find collisions in the SHA-1 hash
> function, which is used in many of
> today's mainstream security products.
> Their attack is estimated to require
> less than 2^69 operations, far fewer
> than the 280 operations previously
> thought needed to find a collision in
> SHA-1. Their work was published at the
> CRYPTO '05 conference. In August 2005,
> an improved attack on SHA-1,
> discovered by Xiaoyun Wang, Andrew Yao
> and Frances Yao, was announced at the
> CRYPTO conference rump session. The
> time complexity of the new attack is
> claimed to be 2^63."

A hash collision attack has further lowered the bar from 2^69 to 2^52 by [McDonald, Hawkes and Piepryzk in 2009](https://eurocrypt2009rump.cr.yp.to/837a0a8086fa6ca714249409ddfae43d.pdf)